# Emergent Property of JADE agent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent, multi-agent

We have to demonstrate an agent system for our assignment, we have to demonstrate following agent features

> 1. Emergent Property
> 2. Adaptability
> 3. Butterfly Effect (small change in locally, make global huge change)

We are going to use JADE as a agent development platform, we already developed basic agents, but we are unable to implement the above behaviours to the agents. can someone have an idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a MAS based on the [ant colony heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) to find the shortest path from an origin to a target. Each ant is modeled as an agent. They communicate with each other through pheromone exchange. The ants' goal is to find a target. The emergent property is the MAS finding the shortest path between the source and the target, even this is not an explicit goal for each agent - this is an emergent behavior of the MAS as a whole. You can change the environment (e.g. terrain or put obstacles) and the ants still must be able to find the target and converge to the new shortest path. A small change in the pheromone evaporation rate can destroy the communication system; therefore, the MAS will not be able to find the shortest path.